# Analysis of limits

Tags: calculus, analysis

Prove directly from the definition that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{6-n-n^2}{n^2+1} = -1 $$

I just want to find a $n>N$ when $\epsilon>0$

I am saying

$$\left|\frac{6-n-n^2}{n^2+1} - (-1)\right| < \epsilon$$

I get to

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{7-n}{n^2+1}< \epsilon$$

Can I not just say that $\left|\frac{7-n}{n^2 + 1}\right| < \left|\frac{7}{n}\right| < \epsilon$

Then I say for $n>N$ if $N=\frac{7}{\epsilon}$

Is this not a good route too solve this?

Comment: Why would |7-n/n^2+1| < |7/n|?

Comment: But for n > 7,  |7-n/n^2+1|<|n/n^2+1|<|n/n^2|=1/n < e if n > max (1/e, 7)

Answer (score 1):

I would say
$$\left\vert \frac{7 - n}{n^2 + 1}\right\vert < \left\vert \frac{7}{n^2 + 1}\right\vert + \left\vert \frac{n}{n^2 + 1} \right\vert \leq \left\vert \frac{7}{n}\right\vert + \left\vert \frac{1}{n}\right\vert = \frac{8}{n} < \epsilon$$
if $n > 8/\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

$\left| \frac{n-7}{n^2 +1}\right| < \epsilon $ is satisfied if $n > \frac{1}{\epsilon} =N(\epsilon)$. 
So given any $\epsilon >0$, $\left| f(n) -L\right| < \epsilon \; \forall \;n > \dfrac{1}{\epsilon} \Rightarrow \underset{n\to \infty}{\lim} f(n) = L$.